# Java code for android app not seem to be working; can't get round the challenge - advice needed

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm a newbie to android development and am currently trying to develop a quiz app using multiple radiogroups as well as checkboxes and imageviews.

I intend for when the user hits the submit button, to collect the responses for the user and send to a second screen to display the results and the users score.

I am able to put together the code to select the radiobuttons and checkboxes. I am also able to stylize the selected answers so that they appear in bold italic typeface. However, I am unable to put together the code to actually collect all these highlighted answers and put them all into a string variable which I can then pass to an intent for the next screen.

My app looks like this: [App Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auaho.jpg)

and my accompanying Java code is here: `package

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    //  This method is called when Question 3 is answered
    public void identifiedAircraft (View view){
        // Get user's input for Question3
        EditText answer3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.aircraft_image_answer);
        Editable answer3Editable = answer3.getText();
        String thirdAnswer = answer3Editable.toString();

    }

    //  This method is called when Question 1 is answered
    public void fastestAircraft (View view) {

        //require to import the RadioButton class
        RadioButton rbRaptor = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.f_22);
        RadioButton rbBlackbird = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.sr_71);
        RadioButton rbBoeing747 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.b_747);
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        //Find the selected answer
        RadioGroup question1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.ques_1);
        String answer1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(question1.getCheckedRadioButtonId()).getText().toString();

        // Style which radio button was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.f_22:
                if (checked)
                    //if F-22 Raptor is selected
                    //set the checked radio button's text style bold italic
                    rbRaptor.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                //set the other two radio buttons text style to default
                rbBlackbird.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                // reqire to import Typeface class
                rbBoeing747.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                    break;
            case R.id.sr_71:
                if (checked)
                    // if SR-71 Blackbird selected
                    //set the checked radio button's text style bold italic
                    rbRaptor.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                //set the other two radio buttons text style to default
                rbBlackbird.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                // reqire to import Typeface class
                rbBoeing747.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                    break;
            case R.id.b_747:
                if (checked)
                    // if Boeing 747 selected
                    //set the checked radio button's text style bold italic
                    rbRaptor.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                //set the other two radio buttons text style to default
                rbBlackbird.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                // reqire to import Typeface class
                rbBoeing747.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                    break;
        }
    }

    //  This method is called when Question 4 is answered
    public void largestCommercialAirliner (View view) {

        //require to import the RadioButton class
        RadioButton rbA380 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.a_380);
        RadioButton rbB747 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.b_747_jet);
        RadioButton rbSu35 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.su_35);
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.a_380:
                if (checked)
                    //if Airbus A380 is selected
                    //set the checked radio button's text style bold italic
                    rbA380.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                //set the other two radio buttons text style to default
                rbB747.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                // reqire to import Typeface class
                rbSu35.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                break;
            case R.id.b_747_jet:
                if (checked)
                    // if Boeing 747 selected
                    //set the checked radio button's text style bold italic
                    rbA380.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                //set the other two radio buttons text style to default
                rbB747.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                // reqire to import Typeface class
                rbSu35.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                break;
            case R.id.su_35:
                if (checked)
                    // if Sukhoi SU-35 is selected
                    //set the checked radio button's text style bold italic
                    rbA380.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                //set the other two radio buttons text style to default
                rbB747.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                // reqire to import Typeface class
                rbSu35.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                break;
        }
    }

    //  This method is called when Question 5 is answered
    public void longestRangeAircraft (View view) {

        //require to import the RadioButton class
        RadioButton rbAn225 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.an_225);
        RadioButton rbAb380 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.ab_380);
        RadioButton rbB777 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.b_777);
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.an_225:
                if (checked)
                    //if Antonov An-225 is selected
                    //set the checked radio button's text style bold italic
                    rbAn225.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                //set the other two radio buttons text style to default
                rbAb380.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                // reqire to import Typeface class
                rbB777.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                break;
            case R.id.ab_380:
                if (checked)
                    // if Airbus A380 is selected
                    //set the checked radio button's text style bold italic
                    rbAn225.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                //set the other two radio buttons text style to default
                rbAb380.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                // reqire to import Typeface class
                rbB777.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                break;
            case R.id.b_777:
                if (checked)
                    // if Boeing 777-200LR is selected
                    //set the checked radio button's text style bold italic
                    rbAn225.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                //set the other two radio buttons text style to default
                rbAb380.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                // reqire to import Typeface class
                rbB777.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                break;
        }
    }

    //  This method is called when Question 6 is answered
    public void bestSellingJetliner (View view) {

        //require to import the RadioButton class
        RadioButton rbB737 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.b_737);
        RadioButton rbA350 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.a_350);
        RadioButton rbA320 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.a_320);
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.b_737:
                if (checked)
                    //if Boeing 737 is selected
                    //set the checked radio button's text style bold italic
                    rbB737.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                //set the other two radio buttons text style to default
                rbA350.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                // reqire to import Typeface class
                rbA320.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                break;
            case R.id.a_350:
                if (checked)
                    // if Airbus A350 selected
                    //set the checked radio button's text style bold italic
                    rbB737.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                //set the other two radio buttons text style to default
                rbA350.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                // reqire to import Typeface class
                rbA320.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                break;
            case R.id.a_320:
                if (checked)
                    // if Airbus A320 is selected
                    //set the checked radio button's text style bold italic
                    rbB737.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                //set the other two radio buttons text style to default
                rbA350.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                // reqire to import Typeface class
                rbA320.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                break;
        }
    }

    //  This method is called when Question 7 is answered
    public void mostNumberOfEngines (View view) {

        //require to import the RadioButton class
        RadioButton rbb36 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.b_36);
        RadioButton rbDoX = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.do_x);
        RadioButton rbB52 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.b_52);
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.b_36:
                if (checked)
                    //if Convair B-36 is selected
                    //set the checked radio button's text style bold italic
                    rbb36.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                //set the other two radio buttons text style to default
                rbDoX.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                // required to import Typeface class
                rbB52.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                break;
            case R.id.do_x:
                if (checked)
                    // if Dornier Do-X selected
                    //set the checked radio button's text style bold italic
                    rbb36.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                //set the other two radio buttons text style to default
                rbDoX.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                // reqire to import Typeface class
                rbB52.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                break;
            case R.id.b_52:
                if (checked)
                    // if Boeing B-52 is selected
                    //set the checked radio button's text style bold italic
                    rbb36.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                //set the other two radio buttons text style to default
                rbDoX.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                // reqire to import Typeface class
                rbB52.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                break;
        }
    }

    //  This method is called when Question 2 is answered
    public void usMilitaryAircraft(View view) {

        //require to import the Checkbox class
        CheckBox cbF35 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_f_35);
        CheckBox cbMig29 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_mig_29);
        CheckBox cbB2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_b_2);
        CheckBox cbA10 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_a_10);
        CheckBox cbEurofighter = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_eurofighter);

        // Is the view now checked?
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

        // Check which checkbox was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.checkbox_f_35:
                if (checked)
                    // F-35 is a US Military Aircraft
                    //set the checkbox's text style bold italic
                    cbF35.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                else
                    // F-35 is not a US Military Aircraft
                    //set the checkbox's text style normal
                    cbF35.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                    break;
            case R.id.checkbox_mig_29:
                if (checked)
                    // Mig-29 is a US Military Aircraft
                    //set the checkbox's text style bold italic
                    cbMig29.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                else
                    // F-35 is not a US Military Aircraft
                    //set the checkbox's text style bold italic
                    cbMig29.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                    break;
            case R.id.checkbox_b_2:
                if (checked)
                    // B-2 is a US Military Aircraft
                    //set the checkbox's text style bold italic
                    cbB2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                else
                    // B-2 is not a US Military Aircraft
                    //set the checkbox's text style bold italic
                    cbB2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                    break;
            case R.id.checkbox_a_10:
                if (checked)
                    // A-10 is a US Military Aircraft
                    //set the checkbox's text style bold italic
                    cbA10.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                else
                    // A-10 is not a US Military Aircraft
                    //set the checkbox's text style bold italic
                    cbA10.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                    break;
            case R.id.checkbox_eurofighter:
                if (checked)
                    // Eurofighter Typhoon is a US Military Aircraft
                    //set the checkbox's text style bold italic
                    cbEurofighter.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                else
                    // Eurofighter Typhoon is not a US Military Aircraft
                    //set the checkbox's text style bold italic
                    cbEurofighter.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                    break;

        }
    }

    public void submitAnswers(View view) {
        // Get user's name
        EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        Editable nameEditable = nameField.getText();
        String name = nameEditable.toString();

    }
}
```

Any ideas to point me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's not working (expected vs. actual outcome)?

Comment: The bit below is me trying to send the user's selections to a string which I can then sent to an intent. However, it throws an error and i cant run the app.

//Find the selected answer
        RadioGroup question1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.ques_1);
        String answer1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(question1.getCheckedRadioButtonId()).getText().toString();

Comment: write the stack trace of the error please

Comment: Error I get when I run the app says "cannot find symbol getText()" and "incompatible types; RadioButton cannot converted to string"

Comment: So, it's a compilation error?!? What do you mean by "run the app"? Are you sure that your code demonstrating the issue is a minimal, verifiable, compiable example?

Comment: _highlighted answers and put them all into a string variable which I can then pass to an intent for the next screen_ This isn't what I'd advise. My idea to "point" you in the right direction would be too add the values to an ArrayList or any Java Collection of your choice when checked. Then pass the arrayList in your intent

Comment: Or a Map.  But yeah you will need to fix the compilation errors first obviously.